# Glm models on R using a binary dependent varible: results & data

Tags: r, binary-data, glm

I am running different glm models in R, with a binary dependent variable and binary and continouous independent variables, but I obtain strange results with the binary independent variables.

This is one of the codes I am running, for example:

```
fit0 <- glm(mention~ media + position,
            data=data,family="binomial",(link=logit))
```

1) First, in the output of the results using stargazer, I do not get all the variable levels, so for example I will get:

```
==============================================
                      Dependent variable:     
                  ----------------------------
                            mention           
                       (1)            (2)     
----------------------------------------------
media2                -0.216         0.000    
                     (0.245)     (17,670.150) 
position              5.147          0.000    
                    (191.373)      (893.444)  
insider_outsider0                   53.132    
                                 (56,734.750) 
insider_outsider1                   53.132    
                                 (30,395.090) 
Constant            -2.831***       -26.566   
                     (0.188)     (14,723.680) 
----------------------------------------------
Observations          1,745          1,745    
Log Likelihood       -286.752       -0.000    
Akaike Inf. Crit.    579.504        10.000    
==============================================
Note:              *p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01
```

So I will get the variable levels of insider_outsider (except the reference level), but not for media for example, where I only get one level, and this is a factor variable with two levels (1 and 2).

2) I get the same results for different variables. For example, check the insider_outsider0 and 1, which have the same result. If I use other variables, I get the same result (53.123), for example chec the "gt_ngo" and "gt_economic" below:

```
==============================================
                      Dependent variable:     
                  ----------------------------
                            mention           
                       (1)            (2)     
----------------------------------------------
media2                -0.216       -0.00000   
                     (0.245)     (17,757.100) 
position              5.147         0.00000   
                    (191.373)      (987.502)  
gt_ngo0                             53.132    
                                 (30,700.250) 
gt_ngo1                             53.132    
                                 (43,071.060) 
Constant            -2.831***       -26.566   
                     (0.188)     (14,765.750) 
----------------------------------------------
Observations          1,745          1,745    
Log Likelihood       -286.752       -0.000    
Akaike Inf. Crit.    579.504        10.000    
==============================================
Note:              *p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01
```

- Could this be because they have esentially the same number of levels 0,1,2 and the level 2 always appears the same number of times for all of these variables, despite that levels 1 and 0 do not appear the same number of times for each of these? And if so, is this a problem? should I re-arrange my data?

Thank you!